# How to change ServerName in apache server?

Tags: apache, server, localhost

I downloaded Apache binary from http://www.apachelounge.com/ After installing, in the `httpd.conf` file on line 220, I changed `#ServerName www.example.com:80` to `ServerName www.example.com:80`. Now everything works fine. The server users the domain name `localhost`. Also `localhost:80` automatically redirects to `localhost`.

> Since `ServerName` is `www.example.com:80` then why does the server work on `localhost` instead of `www.example.com:80`?
>
> If I change every instance of `www.example.com:80` to `mylocalserver:80` then why doesn't the apache server work on `mylocalserver:80`?

Comment: Do you have knowledge of how DNS works? You'll need that to set this up the way you want and understand the problem you're facing

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't give a whole lot of information, but I'll try to answer it anyway.

> Also localhost:80 automatically redirects to localhost.

That's probably not a redirect, but your browser removing the `:80` part as it's the default port on the web.

> Since ServerName is www.example.com:80 then why does the server work on localhost instead of www.example.com:80?

Probably because both `localhost` and `www.example.com` refer to the web server, and the web server responds to both of them. `localhost` is commonly configured to be `127.0.0.1` and thus will refer to your local set-up.

> If I change every instance of www.example.com:80 to mylocalserver:80 then why doesn't the apache server work on mylocalserver:80?

`mylocalserver` might not be referring to anything. Try editing your `hosts` file (`/etc/hosts` on *nix, `%SYSTEM%\Drivers\etc\hosts`) to include `mylocalserver` to refer it to `127.0.0.1` just like `localhost`.

The problems you're having seem to stem from a misunderstanding about the domain names. Domain names translate into IP addresses. `www.example.com` translates to some IP address on the internet, but `localhost` translates into `127.0.0.1` usually, like defined in the `hosts` file. You may also just use the IP address in the `ServerName` variable, such as `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: _...because both localhost and www.example.com refer to the web server, and the web server responds to both of them..._ If both of them refer to same server then why doesn't `www.example.com` open the same files as that opened by `localhost`? And where is `localhost` defined to be `127.0.0.1` in `apache` files?

Comment: @user31782 Like other answers and comments suggest it would be wise to get to know a little bit more about DNS. Apache doesn't define domain names and their IP addresses. I've edited my answer to include some more information.

Comment: @user31782 I assumed `www.example.com` was an example domain name of you.

Comment: `www.example.com` is not my domain. It is used in 220th line of `httpd.conf` file. The line is by default commented with `#`. Without removing the `#` I wasn't able to run `apache`. Now I wonder if `www.example.com` has nothing to do with `localhost` then whh the 220th line has to uncommented?

Comment: Can you tell the location of `%SYSTEM%` folder in window 10?

Comment: I found the location of `hosts` file. But it isn't editable. It gives error when tried to edit.

Comment: Open it using administrator mode. But, I don't think you want to go that way. I think you just want to use `ServerName localhost:80`, or as  I said in my answer: `ServerName 127.0.0.1:80`.

Answer (score 1):

DNS as in name resolution happens before you reach Apache HTTPD Server. When you put a name in your browser or anywhere, that you reach your server or not depends only on that resolution and if resolves the ip of the server you have configured, so it has nothing do be with how httpd is configured that you reach it with one name, and you don't with another.

As for httpd, it works on any name you may want because HTTPD does not know about your DNS setup. It listens on a IP address and if a request reaches the server (through the ip:port it is binded to) then and only then it will check the "Host" http header inside the request to decide to which virtualhost (if more than one and it has been configured properly) to deliver the request.

So you can use any name you like, what matter is how you resolve it and on which ip:port combination you end up.

Comment: If `localhost` is preconfigured to the ip address of apache server then why do I have to uncomment `#ServerName www.example.com:80`? What is the purpose of this line?

Comment: you don't need to uncomment it really. ServerName must be always specified for all your virtualhosts. That's what HTTPD checks against the requested Host header, so if requests goes to www.example.com and lands in the server httpd will know to which virtualhost to deliver this (if there are more than one configured), if there is just 1 virtualhost, no matter the name in it, all requests will land in that virtualhost.

Comment: I don't have virtual host(s). If I don't uncomment the `example.com` line then I get the error `Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name...`

Comment: It's more a warning than a real error. It just means that you haven't set a ServerName in server config context that has a resolvable name.